# JSONGenerator writeString() Internal Error - Can not write text value, expecting field name

Tags: visualforce, json

I'm using the *JSONGenerator writeString()* method, and I'm receiving the following internal server error, "**Can not write text value, expecting field name**"?  The debug logs indicate no errors, and neither does firebug.  The documentation says that the *writeString()* method excepts a String and will write the specified string value (simple enough).

I've checked the known issues site; am I doing something wrong?

Class

```
public class ctrl_extjs_tree4_json {

    public String strJSON {get; private set;}

    public ctrl_extjs_tree4_json()
    {
        List<Account> accounts = [select id, name from Account Limit 3];
        this.strJSON = generateJSON(accounts); 
    }

    public String generateJSON(List<Account> accounts)
    {        
        JSONGenerator g = JSON.createGenerator(true); //boolean indicates pretty format
        g.writeStartArray();
        g.writeStartObject();
        g.writeString('test');
        g.writeEndObject();
        g.writeEndArray();

        return g.getAsString();
    }
}
```

Page

```
<apex:page controller="ctrl_extjs_tree4_json" contentType="text/javascript" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">
{!strJSON}
</apex:page>
```

I'm trying to ultimately produce a list of Accounts with sub list of Contacts (top 5), for an ExtJs tree panel.  Something similar to the example below:

```
[{
    "success": true,
    "children": [
        { "id": 2, "name": "Phil", "leaf": true },
        { "id": 3, "name": "Nico", "expanded": true, "children": [
            { "id": 4, "name": "Mitchell", "leaf": true }
        ]},
        { "id": 5, "name": "Sue", "loaded": true }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With JSON being essentially a key:value pair, it looks like you're attempting to assign a value to a missing attribute. Take a look at the writeFieldName method, to see how to define a JSON field.

Modifying the code to define a key, "Key" to assign the string 'Value' to, should do the trick.

```
JSONGenerator g = JSON.createGenerator(true); //boolean indicates pretty format

g.writeStartArray();
g.writeStartObject();
g.writeFieldName('Key'); // <-- Need to set this
g.writeString('Value');
g.writeEndObject();
g.writeEndArray();

system.debug(g.getAsString());
```

Will output the following:

> 21:57:54.101 (101039000)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|[ {   "Key" : "Value" }
>   ]